# How to get input by user for countdown timer

Tags: java, android, timer, sharedpreferences

I make a countdown java file which have a one button and countdown timer ,i want get input by user for timer in another new activity and save it with the help of shared preference please help me and thanks in advance.
here is timer.java file code

```
package com.cinegoes.www.daily10exercise;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by ever on 7/25/2017.
 */

public class timer extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private boolean timerStarted = false;
    private Button buttonStart;
    public TextView textView;
    private final long startTime = 30 * 1000;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timer);
        buttonStart = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimerActivity(startTime, interval);
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime/1000));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        countDownTimer.start();
        timerStarted = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }


    public class CountDownTimerActivity extends CountDownTimer {
        public CountDownTimerActivity(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textView.setText("Time's up!");
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textView.setText("" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
        }
    }

}
```

here is my timer.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="105dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:background="@drawable/m"
    android:onClick="onclick"
    android:text="skip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Side note : The convention in java is that class name should start with  an upper case letter. Also, your `CountDownTimerActivity` is not an activity but  the class `timer` is. Which can make it hard to follow if you have to call one of them from another file where the inheritance might not be shown directly.

Comment: how will i do it please help me with code

Comment: Android's developper site have a great [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) on how to read and write values from `SharedPreferences`. However, if you don't have to save it for a later use, I would recommend passing it in the intent's `extra`

Comment: You will need to create some UI that enables the user to input an amount of time (like a `Spinner` with minutes from 0 to x or seconds in a `Dialog`). Then you save that into the `SharedPreferences` and load it in the `Activity` where it is needed. You could also format the input time and send it via an Extra to its destination.